# Why can't I ask a question about a career?

Tags: discussion

Why can't I ask a question about career progression? I posted a question last night and the question has been removed! I am a little shocked as to why I can't ask a question here? Is it because it's an opinion based and not a factual question?? If that's the case can someone please give me a factual answer as to where I can ask a question to someone who works in software development so I can get an actual answer please!

Comment: Quora or one of the programming related subreddits of Reddit may be good places to ask. (Check the subreddit side bars, some subs on Reddit have similar strict rules as StackOverflow, though most would allow your question I think).

Comment: Thank you to the man that moved this for me so I didn't have to re post it!!

Comment: Also: Once you get a reputation of 20 points (I think) you can use StackOverflow chat where basically any kind of question or discussion would be allowed.

Comment: Thanks I did post it in the CS sub Reddit on Reddit and no one answered me!! I understand that forums have rules but I'm not trying to cause a debate! I'm just trying to get some opinions from people in this industry on what they look for and which way I should focus my attention! But thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: I can't find any of the rules through the app!! Do I have to use the main site?

Comment: Not all subreddits have explicit rules. They should be in the side bar. I never used the app, so can't say what the differences are. The subreddits are quite different, responses can be of very random quality depending on who gets to see the question at some time. Even worse with the smaller subs with not many subscribers. /r/computerscience has only some 17,500 subscribers while /r/programming has 730,000. So maybe ask there. Though I have definitely seen career questions answered on /r/computerscience. There are links in the cs sub sidebar linking to some general info about cs careers.

Comment: Thanks thorsten !! Much appreciated il have a look and try and repost somewhere else!!

Comment: see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Answer (score 6):

You can't ask such questions here because we, as a community have decided they we don't want them here. You'd probably have to search around Meta for the discussions, but we call this out in [the Help Center's /help/on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 6):

This is a site that is focused on objective answers to questions that are useful to many people over a long period of time. If you ask a question about your career, the answer likely will help only you, will likely only be valid for the time period shortly after you asked it, and will likely be highly opinionated.

Those factors (the answer is relevant only to you, only for now, and only based on opinion) go against the goals of this site. Because of that, the community has decided that career-related questions are inappropriate.